# Appolonius problem: the PPL case

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

I have a problem to understand the PPL Apollonius problem part as stated [here](http://62.182.86.140/main/1398000/36c1f92c5333147142549ffe6a682175/Alfred%20S.%20Posamentier%20-%20Advanced%20Euclidean%20Geometry-Key%20College%20%282002%29.pdf) on the page 202. My problem is, where is the **diameter and the center** of the Thalet circle as given [here](http://fyzika.jreichl.com/main.article/view/1420-eukleidovo-dilo) in the second case as $c$ with $a^2=c\cdot c_a$.Here, I believe $t=a$ and $c=|AP_1|$ and $c_a=|AP_2|$. I can construct the $t$ in question separately on a blank paper but I cannot insert it into the picture in the bottom of the page 202; I think that the Thalet cicrcle and its center is not designated in the picture from the snippet as below:

[image]

Comment: What is the Thalet circle?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos By a Thalet circle I mean a circle over some diameter whose inscribed triangles are right-angled (with hypotenuse being that diameter). I do not know what should be the center of our Thalet circle nor the diameter (a suitable line segment) in this case. In any case I need to construct a **mean average** *t* of segments $AP_2$ and $AP_1$ as in the figure 59 [here](http://fyzika.jreichl.com/main.article/view/1420-eukleidovo-dilo). $AP_1$ in the snippet is $c$ and $AP_2$ is $c_b$ as written in fig. 59.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In other words my question asks, how can I fit the figure 59 in the link to the picture 10.1 in the snippet from the book.

Comment: The PPL (Point Point Line) Apollonius problem is treated [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PPL.shtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, the construction is not difficult. In *Elements, VI, 13* Euclid constructs the (geometric) mean proportional between two given straight lines: place the lines end to end, make them the diameter of a circle, and erect a perpendicular at their meeting point; the segment between the diameter and the circumference is the mean proportional.
[image: Thalet circle]
Thus, in the $PPL$ problem, if $B$, $C$ in the figure above are two points, and the line through them intersects the given line at $A$, and you want the mean proportional between external segment $AB$ and secant $AC$, make $AD=AB$ and construct a circle with diameter $DC$. The perpendicular $AE$ is the mean proportional, which can be laid off on the given straight line as $AF$, $AG$.

The intersections $H$, $J$, then, of perpendiculars at $F$, $G$ with the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ are the centers of two circles tangent at $F$, $G$ and passing through $B$, $C$.

Comment: Could you kindly insert the two circles into your image. The text is dense and I do not follow where the circles should have centers. Two red crosses `x` will do.

Comment: The edited image and text may help to clarify.

Comment: Right. I would like to understand more precisely why we shall construct a circle with diameter $DC$ and **not** $AC$. So why did we created $D$ and not used $ABC$ as given. Thank you.

Comment: Because Euclid’s mean proportional construction requires that the two extremes be situated end to end.  The extremes are AB and AC, but as given they overlap. So I bring AB out as AD, into end to end position with AC.  This gives diameter DC, enabling the construction of mean proportional AE.